# UIL image display in the center of imageView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, universal-image-loader

This is what my android project interface looks like. As you can see, the images are all sticking to the left-hand-side. I tried in XML gridView, imageView putting layout_gravity="center", scaleType="center", adjustviewbounds="true" but none seem to work. I just used this UIL 2 hours ago. I'm new to UIL.

My UIL defaultoption :

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();
```

My XML GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</GridView>
```

imageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGrid_images"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: post your XML code which your gridview in it

Comment: @lgw150 sry my internet was running super slow. I've edited. thanks

Comment: try add this line :android:fadingEdgeLength="1dip"

Comment: @lgw150 oo what is that? but it's not working.. i just want my images to be at the center... :<

Comment: ,i am sorry  the above code not working,what the xml of the item layout ?which in your  gridview adapter.

Comment: @lgw150 it's okay dont worry.. thanks for helping.. i've edited d.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the

```
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
```

to

```
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
```

Finally I got the answer after trying to change all to layout_gravity="center".

Comment: congratulation! but i still do not know why the imagescaletype cause the problem...